# Mean Absolute percentage error getting infinity?

Tags: machine-learning, python, mape

i have written a function for calculating mape using python
here i am mentioning the  function :

```
 def mean_absolute_percentage_error(self,y_true, y_pred): 
    try:
        y_true, y_pred=np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)
        return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100
        
    except Exception as inst:
        self.log.info('<------------- mean_absolute_percentage_error ---------------> ')
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)
        self.log.info(str(exc_type)+' '+str(fname)+' '+str(exc_tb.tb_lineno))
```

Some times  i am getting infinity value as mape ,please suggest on this how to avoid this problem not to get this infinity value as mape.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Does `y_true` have zero values?

Comment: yes some datasets getting zero values ,how to overcome this infinity value in mape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MAPE doesn't make sense when `y_true` can be zero, because division by zero is not defined. You'll have to use a different measurement.

Excluding values where `y_true` is zero is not good practice; sometimes your data is zero, and you need to model that. In other words, the choice of MAPE is the problem, not the data.

MAE will behave similarly, except that it is expressed in terms of the original units, instead of as a percentage. On the other hand, MAE is not differentiable at zero. If differentiability is important, log-cosh loss could be useful as a smooth approximation to MAE, and it's everywhere differentiable.

You may find these answers helpful.
[What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299712/what-are-the-shortcomings-of-the-mean-absolute-percentage-error-mape)

Comment: Thanks for the answer , we need to check y_true is zero or not then only we can use mape as metrics.

Answer (score 0):

What you are calculating is the absolute *relative* error. This can go to infinity for `y_true = 0`.

Comment: i am calculating mean absolute percentage error ,some times i am getting mape as infinity,how to overcome this value .

Comment: if you have y_true = 0, then you cannot use the relative error. One workaround is to add a small value $\epsilon$ to the denominator.

Comment: If `y_true` can take on values of $-\epsilon$, adding $\epsilon$ doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: True. You can add $\epsilon$ to `y_true=0` if `y_true` are observations with some degree of error. If not, you cannot use the MAPE.

Comment: Thanks you for all suggestions.

Comment: If `y_true = 2.2e-16`, then the test `y_true == 0.0` evaluates to `False`, but it's plausible that the value `2.2e-16` arose because of roundoff error (this is at the very edge of double-floating point precision). Working with floating point arithmetic is delicate. Designing a kludge to "patch" MAPE when the target includes 0 is not so simple. Log-cosh and https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13042-011-0031-2 are better alternatives than arbitrarily adding epsilon, because then the value of the loss depends on the choice of $\epsilon$.